# ReactJs dynamic object name in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass dynamic `object` name to a function:

```
handleValid = (type, v) => {
  const validationError = RequestValidation.????.submit(v); // but this is call an object
  const value = v; // this is value
}
```

Here is I pass two parameters to function:

```
this.handleValid(Object.keys(doValid)[i], Object.values(doValid)[i]);
```

So `type` parameter is dynamic, I don't know how can I set dynamic object name here, what I searched and tried:

```
const validationError = RequestValidation.[type].submit(v);
```

Or should use something like:

```
[`${type}`]
```

Of course this not working:

```
const validationError = RequestValidation.type.submit(v);
```

Comment: `RequestValidation[type]` instead of `RequestValidation.[type]`

Comment: Just a typo! `RequestValidation[type]`

Comment: Aw.. :| thanks guys